# Django: Context Processors Returning same value for different Users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a django app in which users can Answer a Question, I'm having some trouble while printing the number of views different users.

Here's my Answer model,

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    content = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntergerField(default=1)
```

Here's how I'm getting the number of views per user inside the `context_processors.py`,

```
def all_views(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        my_user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    else:
        my_user = request.user
    user_views = Answer.objects.filter(user=my_user).aggregate(Sum('views'))
context = {'user_views': user_views }
return context
```

But the problem is that it's returning the number of views of `request.user` for every single user. Means if I log in as `abc (id=1)` having 20 views & visit `xyz (id=2)` profile having 40 views, then it shows 20 views on `xyz` profile as well instead of 40.

Why `if pk:` condition is not working? & How can we fix that? Thank You!

Comment: A context processor takes one, and only one, argument - `request`. It will never receive a `pk` argument so `pk` will always be `None`. Where are you expecting `pk` to come from?

Comment: @solarissmoke Oh, now I get it, my `context processor` has nothing to with the URL user is visiting. I was expecting the `pk` to come from the same URL :( .   Sir, is there any alternative to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context processors are passed only one argument - `request`. Your context processor will never receive a `pk` argument and so `pk` will always be `None`. if `pk` is a keyword argument that is passed to your view, then you *can* access it from the `request` object like so:

```
pk = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('pk')
```

(see the documentation for [`resolver_match`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch)).

That said, *you probably don't want to do this*. Remember that context processors are run for *all* views, many of which might have a `pk` argument that corresponds to a completely different model. This will cause all sorts of problems.

You should consider doing this logic in the appropriate views, rather than in a context processor. Context processors are useful only for globally applicable context - which this isn't.